# javascript json object value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I realize there are 100's of posts about javascript json objects. And all of them imply my code should work, so I am sure I am missing something really stupid. Every attempt to access the json object's key value results in undefined even though the json.parse works fine.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            alert(this.responseText);
            alert(resp.toString());
            alert(resp.exists);
            alert(resp['exists']);
            
         }
    };
```

This results in the following for alerts:

```
"{\"exists\":\"True\"}"
{"exists":"True"}
undefined
undefined
```

What incredibly obvious and dumb thing am I missing? I even attempted to use my exact string in w3schools example and it appears to work fine
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_object_dot

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JSON doesn't have object keys. JSON is a string format, like `'{ "a": 1 }'`. This is a JSON string with 10 characters. Assuming it's stored in a variable `json`, `json[6]` returns `:`.

Comment: `resp.toString()` shouldn't be able to return `{"exists":"True"}` if the data was an object. It'd return `"[object Object]"` as that's the default implementation for all JS objects. It's most likely a string - try `typeof resp`.

Comment: @VLAZ it returned a string... ok thank you for the direction. After re-reading the docs it says it can sometimes return a string, I just missed that. Not sure why

Comment: I had to run json.PARSE(json.PARSE(this.responseText)); Even though in the w3 schools example its parsed into an object with just one. So this makes me a bit nervous

Comment: @noone392 We can tell for sure if you'd show us the raw data. Maybe there is double encoding in your webservice endpoint.

Comment: @DanielW. There was some additional encoding. The first one was identical to the raw. Basically it turns out if the string has escaped characters json.PARSE turns it into a good json string instead of throwing errors. The issue is that in my wordpress endpoint I though I had to encode json before returning, but it does it automatically. So it was essentially double encoded as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it was working using your browser, I got a set of syntax errors when I was trying to test your code. Finally only this code was working

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var resp = xhr.response;
            alert(JSON.stringify( resp)); //{"exists":"True"}
             alert(resp.exists); //"True"
            alert(resp['exists']); //"True"
          }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

but common way to use it

```
    xhr.onload = () => {
        resp= xhr.response;
    }
     xhr.onerror = () => {
        console.log("error " + xhr.status);
    }
```

Comment: ohhh xhr.response; your a scholar and a saint  :-)

Comment: interesting when I do it your way I get alert(JSON.stringify( resp));    // "\n\n{\"exists\":\"True\"}"  and then resp['exists']  //undefined

Comment: typeof(xhr.response) // string hmm the plot thickens

Comment: nvm I missed setting the response type. Thank you Serge